# Adding data to a data.frame to complete a sequence

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

With the data included below, the first bit of which looks like

```
head(dat, 9)
      IndID BinID Freq
1 BHS_034_A     7   20
2 BHS_034_A     8   27
3 BHS_034_A     9   67
4 BHS_034_A    10  212
5 BHS_037_A     5    1
6 BHS_037_A     7   12
7 BHS_037_A     8   65
8 BHS_037_A     9  122
9 BHS_037_A    10  301
```

I want to fill in missing numbers of `BinID` so that all individuals (`IndID`) have a `BinID` sequence from 1 to 10. `Freq` values should be 0 when new values of `BinID` are added.

I hope to accommodate many individuals, but have only included a few here.

This question, is similar to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610652/merge-panel-data-to-get-balanced-panel-data) but here I am trying to also add 0 to the filled in columns.

The data:

```
dat <- structure(list(IndID = c("BHS_034_A", "BHS_034_A", "BHS_034_A", 
"BHS_034_A", "BHS_037_A", "BHS_037_A", "BHS_037_A", "BHS_037_A", 
"BHS_037_A", "BHS_068_A", "BHS_068_A", "BHS_068_A", "BHS_068_A", 
"BHS_068_A", "BHS_068_A", "BHS_068_A", "BHS_070_A", "BHS_070_A", 
"BHS_070_A", "BHS_071_A", "BHS_071_A", "BHS_071_A", "BHS_071_A", 
"BHS_071_A", "BHS_071_A", "BHS_071_A", "BHS_071_A", "BHS_071_A"
), BinID = c(7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L), Freq = c(20L, 27L, 67L, 212L, 1L, 12L, 65L, 122L, 301L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 14L, 104L, 454L, 7L, 90L, 470L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 
7L, 18L, 19L, 15L, 31L, 344L)), .Names = c("IndID", "BinID", 
"Freq"), row.names = c(NA, 28L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tidyr` provides the complete function that allows you to find missing combinations in your dataset:

```
tidyr::complete(dat, IndID, BinID = 1:10)
```

Comment: Great new function for me!

Comment: and with the `fill` argument, it is possible to fill in with 0 rather than NA. `fill = list(Freq = 0)).

Answer (score 1):

Using:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[CJ(BinID = 1:10, IndID = IndID, unique = TRUE), on = .(IndID, BinID)]
```

Or:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(IndID) %>% 
  expand(BinID = 1:10) %>% 
  left_join(., dat)
```

gives:

> ```
>         IndID BinID Freq
>  1: BHS_034_A     1   NA
>  2: BHS_037_A     1   NA
>  3: BHS_068_A     1   NA
>  4: BHS_070_A     1   NA
>  5: BHS_071_A     1   NA
>  6: BHS_034_A     2   NA
>  7: BHS_037_A     2   NA
>  8: BHS_068_A     2   NA
>  9: BHS_070_A     2   NA
> 10: BHS_071_A     2    6
> 11: BHS_034_A     3   NA
> 12: BHS_037_A     3   NA
> 13: BHS_068_A     3    2
> 14: BHS_070_A     3   NA
> 15: BHS_071_A     3   11
> 16: BHS_034_A     4   NA
> 17: BHS_037_A     4   NA
> 18: BHS_068_A     4    1
> 19: BHS_070_A     4   NA
> 20: BHS_071_A     4   11
> 21: BHS_034_A     5   NA
> 22: BHS_037_A     5    1
> 23: BHS_068_A     5    1
> 24: BHS_070_A     5   NA
> 25: BHS_071_A     5    7
> 26: BHS_034_A     6   NA
> 27: BHS_037_A     6   NA
> 28: BHS_068_A     6   NA
> 29: BHS_070_A     6   NA
> 30: BHS_071_A     6   18
> 31: BHS_034_A     7   20
> 32: BHS_037_A     7   12
> 33: BHS_068_A     7    4
> 34: BHS_070_A     7   NA
> 35: BHS_071_A     7   19
> 36: BHS_034_A     8   27
> 37: BHS_037_A     8   65
> 38: BHS_068_A     8   14
> 39: BHS_070_A     8    7
> 40: BHS_071_A     8   15
> 41: BHS_034_A     9   67
> 42: BHS_037_A     9  122
> 43: BHS_068_A     9  104
> 44: BHS_070_A     9   90
> 45: BHS_071_A     9   31
> 46: BHS_034_A    10  212
> 47: BHS_037_A    10  301
> 48: BHS_068_A    10  454
> 49: BHS_070_A    10  470
> 50: BHS_071_A    10  344
> ```